# Three.js multiple Canvases and Shader

Tags: three.js, shader

1.

I am trying to set up multiple canvases on a page like the given examples on threejs.org.

My basic code is like this:

```
var scene, camera, controls, renderer, pointLight, geometry, material;
var container, position, dimensions, apps = [];
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

function preView( id ){

    apps.push( new App( id ) );

    //animate(); // if i call this here, all canvases renders once

    function App( id ) {

        container = $('#preView_' + id);
        dimensions = { width: container.width(), height: container.height()};

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, dimensions.width/dimensions.height, 1, 5 * radius);
        camera.position.x = 0;
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.z = 100;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        /* add meshes */


        /* ======================= */

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);

        container.append(renderer.domElement);

        this.animate = function() {
            if( camera.position.z > -(1/3) * 100 )
            {

                /* simple fly through the scene */
                camera.position.x += 0.05;
                camera.position.y += 0.05;
                camera.position.z -= 0.1;
            }
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
            render();
        };
    }
}


function animate(){
    for ( var i = 0; i < apps.length; ++i ) {
        apps[ i ].animate();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function render(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

The strange thing what happends is, that only the last canvas renderes (at all) if i call `animate();` after all canvases are drawn. And if i call `animate();` in the `preView();` Function, all sences are rendered once but only the last canvas renderes the 'camera fly through'. But a `console.log(apps[i]);` in the `animate();` function go through all apps, but dont render the scene.

What do i do wrong here?

2.

Also i try to achieve [this](http://codepen.io/_j4nk3y/pen/mAxrGA?editors=0010) shader effect for every object which i declare as 'light', nomatter which position it has in the scene.
I tried to play a little with all position values in the shaders with absolutly no effect.
The only effect was in the `VolumetericLightShader` on line 333.

I hope for any Hints here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put all the variables, except apps=[], in App( id ) function. Thus you'll make them local for App. In your case now, every time you call

   ```
   new App( id )
   ```

   you put information in global variables which you created once. So in those variables you have the data you've stored there since last call of App( id ).
   It means that you re-write the data in global variables. The same about the render() method. Put it inside the App() function too. As you mentioned about the example from Threejs.org, you had to notice where this method is stored. It's inside the App() function there. Sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/hg2cLmku/)
2. Maybe it would be easier to use the technique of lens flares. https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lensflares.html